# PhoneGap: JavaScript Focus and Blur event in iOS / Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios, cordova

I would like to detect the focus and blur event in HTML input text box in a PhoneGap mobile application. 
For iOS, the behaviour is as expected - When the textbox is in focus (textbox is clicked), alert message `Focus!` is displayed. When the textbox loses focus (keyboard is closed / move on to next input box), alert message `Blur!` is shown.

However, for Android, when I click the textbox (the textbox is in focus), alert message `Focus!` and `Blur!` are displayed continuously which means that it is focus, blur, focus, blur, ...

How can this be avoided so that it can align with iOS?

In JavaScript:

```
var txtValue = document.getElementByID('txtValue');
txtValue.addEventListener('focus', function() {
    alert('Focus!');
});
txtValue.addEventListener('blur', function() {
    alert('Blur!');
});
```

In HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="txtValue" />
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because when you show the alert, focus goes into that dialog, losing it from the input field and dispatching blur event. And when you close the dialog, focus goes back into input field, dispatching focus event.

I don't know the exact fix for this. Maybe using custom overlay dialog / lightbox instead of window.alert() could be one solution.

Other option could be comparing where the event is dispatched from, eg (not tested):

```
var txtValue = document.getElementById('txtValue');
txtValue.addEventListener('focus', function(evt) {
    if (evt.nodeName && evt.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'input') {
        alert('focus!');
    }
});
```